# Background Clip not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli, react-styleguidist

```
        <Text style={styles.text}>text</Text>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    backgroundImage: "path-to-image",
    WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
    backgroundClip: "text",
    color: "transparent"
  }
});
```

it say 'Invalid props.style key supplied to Text`

What am i doing wrong? What it should be?

Answer (score 1):

React Native doesn't have `background-clip` property https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props

Use instead React Native MaskedView https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/masked-view